# Do HTML5 iFrame Sandbox counts views?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-analytics

Does setting the html5 iframe `sandbox` attribute stop google analytics measuring page views, because the scripts is not allowed when sandbox is set?

```
<iframe id="iframe_auto" src="" scrolling="yes" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Where is the google script placed? In the Iframe's source itself, or in the Iframe's PARENT Document's source?

Answer (score 0):

An empty sandbox attribute will not allow scripts to run so Google analytics will not run inside the iframe as it is 100% JavaScript dependent.