# Do iFrame count page views?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

If you load a site in iFrame, does it count as their page views?

Does Google Analytics count it as a page view?

Comment: Just as in [your other related question here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927519/do-html5-iframe-sandbox-counts-views): we still need to know where is the google script placed? In the Iframe's source itself, or in the Iframe's PARENT Document's source?

Answer (score 4):

If there is a Google Analytics script in the iframe, it will be triggered any time the iframe is loaded by any host page and it will count as it's own page view.

As far as an iframe is concerned, it is a stand-alone web page.  It can figure out if it's framed or not, but only if it chooses to do so.  In all other ways, it is a normal stand-alone web page.